# Крестики нолики с++

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа, условия

Решил я написать на первый взгляд простенькую игру - "**крестики нолики**" и столкнулся с проблемой.
Каждая клетка имеет свой номер, пользователь вводит номер клетки и эта клетка заполняется буквой Х, далее программа с помощью генератора псевдо случайных чисел в интервале от 1 до 9(включительно) заполняла бы одну клетку ноликом, но вот проблема в том, что программа может изменить допустим крестик на нолик. Генератор может выдать номер клетки, которая уже заполнена либо ноликом либо крестиком. Как мне обойти эту проблему? Я так понимаю, надо получить индексы элементов, которые равны 0, что бы потом из этих индексов случайным образом выбрать один, далее заполнить его значением 2 (нолик), после чего из других оставшихся выбрать другой тоже случайным образом. Тем самым **не дать программе перезаписать элементы, которые не равны нулю.**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std ;

int random (int min, int max)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int num = min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
  return num;
}

int main() {
int number; 
int a;
string arr[9] = {"  " ,"  " ,"  " ,"  " ,"  " ,"  " ,"  ","  ","  "}; //массив, который будет заполняться строчным типом данных (Х или О)  а потом выводиться. 
int arr1[9] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} ;// массив дублирующий предыдущий массив, но уже с целочисленным типом данных. (0 - пустые клетки, 1 - крестик, 2 - нолик) 

cout << "Привет, сыграем?)"<<endl<<endl;

cout << "\t1\t|\t2\t|\t3\t"<<endl<<"   -------------------"<<endl<<
"\t4\t|\t5\t|\t6\t"<<endl<<"   -------------------" <<endl<<
"\t7\t|\t8\t|\t9\t"<<endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
cout<<"Введи номер клетки: " << endl ;

cout << "\t" <<arr[0]<<"\t|\t" <<arr[1]<<"\t|\t" <<arr[2]<<"\t"<<endl<<"   -------------------"<<endl<<
"\t" <<arr[3]<<"\t|\t"<<arr[4]<<"\t|\t" <<arr[5]<<"\t"<<endl<<"   -------------------" <<endl<<
"\t"<<arr[6]<<"\t|\t"<<arr[7]<<"\t|\t"<<arr[8]<<
"\t"<<endl;

cin >> a;
arr[a-1] = "X" ;//массив для чтения пользователем
arr1[a-1] = 1;// массив для чтения программой

random();
number = random (0, 8);

for(int i =0; i<9;i++){
arr[number] = "O";// что б пользователь видел ход
arr1[number] = 2;//заполнение клетки случайно сгенерированным индексом 

}
}
}
```

Каким образом можно исключить уже заполненные клетки, что б прога не переписывала занятые значения

Comment: У вас должен быть массив клеток, которые уже заполнены. И когда будете определять случайное число, проверяйте, что этого числа еще нет в том массиве.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 - генерировать случайные числа и проверять занятость. Если ячейка занята - генерировать новое число.

Вариант 2 - собирать индексы свободных клеток в массив, и генерировать случайный индекс в рамках этого массива.

Вариант 3 - изначально случайным образом перемешать все 9 индексов, и когда нужен очередной ход - брать из этой последовательности первый пока еще свободный индекс.

Вариант 4... впрочем, трех уже должно хватить :)

Вариант 5 - играть детерминированно, стараясь победить (что вряд ли удастся), а не сыграть в поддавки :)

Answer (score 0):

Создай цикл и проверяй в нем рандомное число

```
while(true)
{
    number = random(0, 8)
    If (arr[number] == 0)
    {
         arr[number] = 2;
         break;
    }
}
```

А ещё в твоём коде лучше написать функцию, возвращающую символ в зависимости от числа массива, а не создавать два массива.